# Confusing in ajax success function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some serverside script for check user:

```
function passlog($use,$pass){
        $Use = mysql_real_escape_string($use);
        $Pass= mysql_real_escape_string($pass);
$res=mysql_query($sql) or die(_ERROR26.":".mysql_error());
  $dat=mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_NUM);  //it will get result ex. "3"
        if(mysql_affected_rows()>0) {
                        echo $dat[0];
                        }else{
                        echo "No specified data";
        }
return 0;
}
```

after that if that script get result as "3" it will return to ajax success function. Then do the next job, there is if show result as "3" It will send some value to another variable.

```
$.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"process3.php",
        data:params,
        cache:false,
        async:false,
        success: function(res){
                               $("#dialog").dialog('close');
                               var now = new Date();
                               var months = new Array('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12');
                               var date = ((now.getDate()<10) ? "0" : "")+ now.getDate();
                               function fourdigits(number) {
                                         return (number < 1000) ? number + 1900 : number;
                                         }
                               var today =  months[now.getMonth()] + "/" +date+ "/" + (fourdigits(now.getYear()));

                               switch(parseInt(res)){
                                     case "3":
                                               $("#appdate").text(today);         //not work
                                               $("#app").text($("#user").val()); //not work
                                               break;
                          }
                            $.ajax({
                                    type:"post",
                                    url:"process1.php",
                                    data:"tversion="+matches+"&action=tunermatches",
                                    cache:false,
                                    async:false,
                                    success: function(res){
                                                 $('#tunedat').replaceWith(
                                                                                    "<div id='tunedat'><h6>" + res + "</h6></div>"
                                                                  );
                                                 }
                                     });
                },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
```

but, its not work and i get no error message. Whether my ajax wrong?

---

i have ajax inside ajax too.
[image: div id= app inside a cell below "issue by"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `switch` gets a number but your `case` is for a string:

```
switch(parseInt(res)){
    case "3":
```

Without any other fixes to your code, this should be changed to

```
switch(parseInt(res)){
    case 3:
```

Comment: still not work. the `$("#app").text($("#user").val())` is send value from textfield into div.

Comment: So `$("#appdate").text(today);` is working now? And isn't `$("#app").text($("#user").val())` supposed to do that? Set the value from the user textfield as the text for the div? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: both not work, exactly i want after fill some value inside `user` then do click at button ajax will post that value to check user, if ok it will get result as `3` then if result `3` the div will get value from user.

Comment: So what happens on click? Have you tried debugging using Firebug if on Firefox or Chrome's developer tools? Is the request being made? What's the response from the server?

Comment: for response from server is `3` nothing error in developer tools

Comment: have you any advise how to show `user` value into a cell below "issue by"

Comment: @no.good.at.coding: its work if I delete ajax inside ajax. why?

Comment: I'm not sure why it would work when you remove it - there's no restriction on making ajax calls within the success callback of another ajax call, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: By try to hide one by one script I can show the result what I want. thanks.